# Javascript rename function (not variable name)

Tags: javascript, function, rename

I am trying to change the name of the function that is given by `.toString()`, or create a new function with a new name but the same body.

```
function func() {}
func.toString() // returns 'function func() {}'
changename(func, "newname") // this is the functionality that I am trying to achieve
func.toString() // should now return 'function newname() {}'
```

I have tried using `Object.defineProperty()` which sucessfully updates the value returned by `func.name` but not `func.toString()`.

```
Object.defineProperty(func, "name", {
  value: "newname",
  writable: true,
});
func.name // returns 'newname'
func.toString() // still returns 'function func() {}'
```

Edit: Reason for wanting to do this
I need take take an arbitrary function with an unknown name and write it to a file with a known name, for example (using nodejs):

```
const fs = require("fs");
changename(func, "newname");
fs.writeFileSync("tmp.js", func.toString());
```

tmp.js then contains:

```
function newname() {}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why do you need to change the function name? What is the problem you try to solve with that?

Comment: I'm still not sure why you want to be writing functions to files - that also seems like an XY problem but at least you can just assign the function to a variable - `const newName = function oldName(){}` will make `newName` the handle for the function for that file. It also changes it from function declaration to an expression, which will have an impact on hoisting but its very cheap way to do a "rename".

Comment: Do you actually need to change the callable name or can you just override the toString property of the function? Alternatively you could use the function constructor to make a new function named newname that just calls your original function.

Comment: I've been in the position of doing this (specifically: functions created by a template system (doT) that I need in the form of object property values), and I just stripped out the name with a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to do is write the code of the function to a file, just regex replace the name with whatever you want:

```
let func = // whatever;

let funcCode = func.toString();
funcCode = funcCode.replace(/^function [^(]*(.*)$/, "function newName$1");
```

Now `funcCode` has the text you can dump out to a file.

Changing the reported "name" property of an actual function object is another story entirely, and is either impossible or impractical at best. If you're just working with the *text* of the function, it's easy.

Comment: This works, thanks. Might be worth adding to your answer that it is not possible to actually change the name of the function object, so this is the best work around.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with extending toString function, this should work:

```
function func() {}
func.toString() // returns 'function func() {}'
changeName=function(funcToExtend, name){
    funcToExtend.toString = () => name;
}
changeName(func,"new name");
func.toString(); // new name
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to change how the toString function works. I don't think this is a good solution but I came up with this:

```js
function test(){
    console.log('hello');
}
test.newName = 'helloFunc';
test.toString = function(){
    var str = Function.prototype.toString.call(this);
    return 'function ' + this.newName + str.substring(str.indexOf('('), str.length);

}

console.log(test.toString());
```

I believe that a much nicer solution could implement the Function constructor. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: `var str = this.toStringReg()` can be replaced with a slightly more generic `var str = Function.prototype.toString.call(this)`, so you don't need to add the `toStringReg` property to the function.

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of that. I made the change, however, at the end of the day, the regex solution is much nicer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want just a new String with the new name, you can do this way:

```js
function func() {}
console.log(func.toString())

Object.prototype.changeName = function (newName) {
  return "function " + newName + "(){}";
}

let newNameFunction = func.changeName("newName")
console.log(newNameFunction);
```

But this way, you don't have the body of the function.

Comment: Surely the OP omitted the body of the function for clarity, not because they are working with empty functions and need to generate an empty function with a new name. They seem capable enough to create empty functions from scratch. Their purpose was clearly stated to take existing functions and rename them on the fly. This is a non-answer using similar techniques found in possible answers.